# How to batch upload ECW files to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, ecw

I have about 10000 ECW files. I want to show them as layers in GeoServer, but I need to upload them one by one. How can I upload them in bulk?
Or how can I publish this 10000 ECW satellite images with Leaflet?

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/importer/guireference.html

I installed GeoServer in importer plugin but it gives opps error

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far and why it is not working for you. Can you upload a single ECW file?